# How to [flat] merge Merge Multiple Arrays into List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, merge

How can I [flat] merge multiple arrays into a single `List<String>`?

For example:

```
private String title[] = { "Cup Cake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo",
        "Ginger Bread", "Honey Comb", "Icecream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean" };

private String desc[] = { "version: 1.5", "version: 1.6",
        "version: 2.0 & 2.1", "version: 2.2", "version: 2.3",
        "version: 3.0", "version: 4.0", "version: 4.1" };

private int thumb[] = {3,4,7,8,10,11,15,16};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you wish to add the array of Integers into the same List of Strings:

```
import java.util.Arrays;     
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  

public class StringArrayTest  
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        String title[] = { "Cup Cake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo",
        "Ginger Bread", "Honey Comb", "Icecream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean" };

        String desc[] = { "version: 1.5", "version: 1.6",
        "version: 2.0 & 2.1", "version: 2.2", "version: 2.3",
        "version: 3.0", "version: 4.0", "version: 4.1" };

        int thumb[] = {3,4,7,8,10,11,15,16};

        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(title));
        nameList.addAll(Arrays.asList(desc));
        nameList.add(Arrays.toString(thumb)); //adds thumb as a single string entry
   }  
}
```

Comment: That last call will add a single string representing the entire integer array

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29 Well, he didn't specify so I just added an answer for his consideration. If he wishes to add the integers delimited by the commas, he could always use something along the line of : `Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"))` or `Arrays.asList(string.split(" , "))`.

Comment: It is not correct. The Arrays.asList(..) creates a fixed-size list (see javadoc) and the NameList.addAll(..) will throw an UnsupportedOperationException. You must create a normal ArrayList to collect into it.

Comment: It cannot be compiled.  `private int thumb[]` -> `int[] thumb` `nameList.addAll(Arrays.toString(thumb));` -> `nameList.add(Arrays.toString(thumb));`

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
List<Object> list =
    Stream.of(Stream.of(title), Stream.of(desc), IntStream.of(thumb).mapToObj(i -> i))
    .flatMap(s -> s)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Also, if all arrays are of the same type, you can simply write `Stream.of(title, desc, thumb, ..., whatever).flatMap(Stream::of).collect(toList())`, especially if you want to merge quite a few of them. If you want to merge into a new array (not into list), replace the `.collect(...)` part with `.toArray(String[]::new)`

Comment: @YooryN. for me `.flatMap(Stream::of)` did not want to compile, I had to fall back to `.map(o -> o.stream()).flatMap(o -> o)` even if all the lists I wanted to merge contained the same type.

Comment: @E. Körner Arrays and lists are different things, and hence different methods are used to work with them. In case of lists, you still can simplify to a single call of `.flatMap(o -> o.stream())` (or its equivalent with method reference).

Answer (score 1):

Source:

```
private String title[] = { "Cup Cake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo",
    "Ginger Bread", "Honey Comb", "Icecream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean" };

private String desc[] = { "version: 1.5", "version: 1.6",
    "version: 2.0 & 2.1", "version: 2.2", "version: 2.3",
    "version: 3.0", "version: 4.0", "version: 4.1" };`

private int thumb[] = {3,4,7,8,10,11,15,16};
```

Assuming you want to have a list of Strings:

```
final List<String> original = Stream.of(title, desc).collect(Collectors.toList());
original.addAll(Stream.of(thumb).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over each of them. Also, each element in the list will need to be the same type (unless you want them all to be Object. try:

```
list List<String> = new ArrayList<String>
// First array
for (String s: title) {
    list.add(s);
}
// Do the same for other arrays
```

Alternatively

```
list List<Object> = new ArrayList<Object>
// First array
for (Object s: title) {
    list.add(s);
}
```

In the second case, the list is just less useful since you would have to end up manually type checking everthing before calling any methods on the elements.

Answer (score 0):

All your elements need to be of the same type, for example String.

You can try something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  

public class StringArrayTest  
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        String title[] = { "Cup Cake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo",
        "Ginger Bread", "Honey Comb", "Icecream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean" };

        String desc[] = { "version: 1.5", "version: 1.6",
        "version: 2.0 & 2.1", "version: 2.2", "version: 2.3",
        "version: 3.0", "version: 4.0", "version: 4.1" };

        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
        newList.addAll( Arrays.asList(title));
        newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(desc));

        for (String e : newList)  
        {  
            System.out.println(e);  
        } 
   }  
}
```